# Unsupported operand during operation between columns in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a .csv files in the folder that I am loading into the dictionary and then I am performing several operations with them: merging based on the condition and removing the first row. 
After that I am trying to find the difference between two columns in each of the dataframes and record the result in new column.

I have the following code:

```
path="directory"

### loading the files
files=[f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
dictionary={}
for file in files:
    dictionary[file]=pd.read_csv(path+'/'+file+'.csv')
results={}



### merging dataframes and removing the first row

for df in dictionary:
    results[str(df)[:-9]+'merged_with_H07']=pd.merge(dictionary['H07_2017_SS_TOPS_AZPU'],dictionary[str(df)], on=['FORMATION'], how='outer').fillna(0)
    results[str(df)[:-9]+'merged_with_H07'] = results[str(df)[:-9]+'merged_with_H07'].iloc[1:]



### finding the difference

for df in results:
    results[str(df)]['delta_tvdss']=results[str(df)]['TVD_SCS']-results[str(df)]['TVDSS']
```

Unfortunately in the end there is an error coming out as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 968, in na_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 220, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 1048, in wrapper
    result = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 970, in na_op
    result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
  File "C:\Users\abkk1l\PycharmProjects\edX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 447, in masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], com.values_from_object(yrav[mask]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

I have looked through the data and found no str in the columns that I use for subtraction. What could be the reason?

#

The solution is adding `.astype(float)` to calculation part:

```
before:
results[str(df)]['delta_tvdss']=results[str(df)]['TVD_SCS']-results[str(df)]['TVDSS']

after:
   results[str(df)]['delta_tvdss']=results[str(df)]['TVD_SCS_y'].astype(float)-results[str(df)]['TVD_SCS_x'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Please paste the full error trace.

Comment: In the problem `df` the 2nd column must be object dtype and contain one or more strings.